# Scikit classification on categorical variables - feature importance and hot encoding -which first?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a dataframe comprising 23 categorical varables. I would eventually like to build a predictor model (Decision tree/Random forest) to predict if someone will attend an interview or not. This is my target variable. I will use Scikit for this task.

Questions:

As these are categorical variables am I right in saying I need to Hot encode each of my 23 categorical variables before splitting into a train, test and validation sets?

I have also been told to use Feature importance, but I am unsure if I use this before or after Hot encoding? It was my understanding that feature importance will help to reduce the number of features I have to Hot encode, in other words I use feature importance before Hot encoding.

However, the `RandomForestClassifier()`, I attempted to use for feature importance will not work with strings:

**Input**: `forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=250, random_state=0)
    forest.fit(X, y)`

**Output**: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Single'`

What would be the best way to go about this please?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert to one-hot encoding. Scikit only supports numerical features, so without converting the strings to numbers you cannot even do the feature importance in scikit.

Comment: This is very helpful-Thank you :)